# Prompt window won't open when clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html, css, prompt

I've got an assignment where I have to see if the entered number is an Armstrong number, the problem is when I click on the button the prompt window doesn't show up, and it only occurs when I have the rest of the function written out. When it is by itself the prompt window shows.

```
function armNum(){
    var num = prompt("Enter a number between 0 and 999!: ");
    var firstNum;
    var secondNum;
    var thirdNum;
    if(num < 100 && num > 0)
    {
        firstNum = num/10;
        secondNum = num%10;
        var StrongNum = (firstNum**3) + (secondNum**3);
        if( num == StrongNum)
        {
            document.getElementById("ispis").innerHTML = "nummber " + num + " is an armstrong number!"
        }
    else

        {
            document.getElementById("ispis").innerHTML = "number" + num + "is not an armstrong number!"
        }
    }
    if(num > 99 && num < 1000)
    {
        firstNum = num/100;
        secondNum = (num/10)%10;
        thirdNum = num % 10;
        var StrongNum = (firstNum**3) + (secondNum**3) = (thirdNum**3);
        if( num == StrongNum)
        {
            document.getElementById("ispis").innerHTML = "nummber " + num + " is an armstrong number!"
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("ispis").innerHTML = "number" + num + "is not an armstrong number!"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a error in tnis line `= (firstNum**3) + (secondNum**3) = (thirdNum**3);` you have used '=' instead off  '+'

Answer (score 1):

1. You have a mistake at this string (change "=" to "+"):

   var StrongNum = (firstNum**3) + (secondNum**3) = (thirdNum**3);
2. You don`t call function
3. try to add  after your function

   armNum();

Answer (score 0):

there is a error in tnis line `= (firstNum**3) + (secondNum**3) = (thirdNum**3);` you have used '=' instead off '+' & you

```js
function armNum(){
    var num = prompt("Enter a number between 0 and 999!: ");
    var firstNum;
    var secondNum;
    var thirdNum;
    if(num < 100 && num > 0)
    {
        firstNum = num/10;
        secondNum = num%10;
        var StrongNum = (firstNum**3) + (secondNum**3);
        if( num == StrongNum)
        {
            alert( "nummber " + num + " is an armstrong number!")
        }
    else

        {
            alert( "number" + num + "is not an armstrong number!");        }
    }
    if(num > 99 && num < 1000)
    {
        firstNum = num/100;
        secondNum = (num/10)%10;
        thirdNum = num % 10;
        var StrongNum = (firstNum**3) + (secondNum**3)+(thirdNum**3);
        if( num == StrongNum)
        {
            alert( "nummber " + num + " is an armstrong number!");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("number" + num + "is not an armstrong number!");
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<body onload=armNum()>
</body>
```